# how to move to correct definition in qtcreator with cmake projects

Tags: qt, cmake, qt-creator

I have cmake projects in **QT Creator v4.5.0**.

In build, I do "**cmake build**" and "**cmake install**".
What **cmake install** does is install header files and compiled libraries to a target directory.

Then, in QT Creator, I want to go to a definition of class clicking (Ctrl + left mouse button) as usual.

Where QT Creator brings me is the related header file, yes, but not the header file in source codes directory, but in target directory.

This is dangerous because if you edit the file in target directory and build it, you will lose your change, which makes the use of (Ctrl + left mouse button) impossible.

Here is the only thing that I found what QT tells about this:

[moving to symbol definition/declaration](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-coding-navigating.html#moving-to-symbol-definition-or-declaration)

How can I use it as correct way?

Comment: As I noticed myself, and mentioned all over again in several SO comments, `cmake` support in Qt Creator is generally lacking. If possible use `qmake`, that's the native project management utility for Creator, and Qt projects in general.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, but why don't simply open the CMakeLists.txt in QtCreator and specify the build directory in the toolkit, then compile and run from qtcreator from this build dir...

Comment: There are lots of projects using by lots of people. We need to deploy in install directory.

Comment: Did you change the include path or did you use <> to include header files and not ""? That way the header files in the target folder are first in your include path.

Comment: We use "" to include.